# Dominated convergence theorem for a multivariate polynomial

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

Consider the following integral of a multivariate polynomial of order $n$, e.g.,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^{1-x} \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^{n-k}y^{k} dxdy$$

I know the integrand to be always in [0,1], therefore the function $g(x)=1$ will upper bound the integrand.

Can I apply right-away the dominated convergence theorem to this function to bring the limit inside the integral? Or does it need a proof?

Comment: You also need to know that $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^{n-k}y^{k}$ converges pointwise almost everywhere.